# Count row-wise in stata

Tags: stata

I am using a table that is relatively unstructured in stata. I am trying to count the number of observations between two specific rows by a group. Specifically, I want to count the number of observations between the row with the value TITLE and the blank row, as seen below:

```
v1                                   id
AGENCY: HHS-ACF                      1
EXPIRATION DATE: 11/30/2023          1
TITLE: Annual Survey of Refugees     1
TOTAL ANNUAL RESPONSES:              1
3,000                                1
ASSOCIATED INFORMATION COLLECTIONS:  1
TITLE                                1
ORR-9 Annual Survey of Refugees      1
Introduction Letter and Postcard     1

AGENCY: HHS-ACF                      2
EXPIRATION DATE: 02/29/2024          2
TITLE: Unaccompanied Refugee Minors Program: 2 ORR-3 Placement Report and ORR-4 Outcomes  
Report                               2
TOTAL ANNUAL RESPONSES:              2
8,058                                2
ASSOCIATED INFORMATION COLLECTIONS:  2
TITLE                                2
ORR-3 (Unaccompanied Refugee Minors Placement Report) - State Agencies             2
ORR-4 (Unaccompanied Refugee Minors Outcomes Report) - State Agencies             2
ORR-3 (Unaccompanied Refugee Minors Placement Report) - URM Provider Agencies      2
ORR-4 (Unaccompanied Refugee Minors Outcomes Report) - URM Provider Agencies      2
ORR-4 (Unaccompanied Refugee Minors Outcomes Report) - URM Youth
```

I want the final dataset to have a count of the total values between the blank and TITLE with an accompanying unique ID. I have already been able to construct the ID but I can't get the count right. What is the best way to do that?
I want the final dataset to look like:

```
ID  count
1   2
2   5
```

Comment: Please show the desired output for the example given above

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single column `v1`, then you can do this:

```
gen id=sum(v1=="")+1
bysort id: gen ct=_N-_n
keep if v1=="TITLE"
drop v1
```

Output:

```
       id   ct  
  1.    1    2  
  2.    2    5
```